# Drop pandas rows for entire group based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

```
import seaborn
df = seaborn.load_dataset('flights')
```

I want to drop the years where the number of average passengers per year is less than 200. I tried this

```
df[df.groupby(['year'])['passengers'].mean() > 200]
```

but get this error:

```
*** pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).
```

In the correct answer, the dataframe should drop rows for these years:
1949, 1950, 1951, 1952

Comment: I guess you want: `df[df.groupby('year')['passengers'].transform('mean') > 200]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you need to:

- **group** by *year*,
- **filter** groups, checking whether the mean of *passengers* in the
  current group is > 300.

So the code should be:

```
df.groupby(['year']).filter(lambda x: x.passengers.mean() > 300)
```